# Openlayers-3 - Is it possible to reload a single layer?

Tags: openlayers-3

As the title says. I want to be able to reload a layer that is displayed on the map. Is there a way to do this (directly)?

So not map.render() or map.renderSync(), because these renders only change the view after scrolling or changing the view.

Comment: What kind of layer/source do you want to reload?

Comment: A huge GeoJSON polygon vector

Answer (score 0):

To reload a geojson vector layer you have to clear it first and then do the same as you did in first place: loading de layer and setting the layer source:

```
vectorLayerSource.clear();
loadVectorLayer(url);
```

The steps for loading the geojson layer depends on your configuration, assuming that you have it in an external geojson file you could do it like that (using jquery):

```
function loadVectorLayer(url) {
  $.when(
    $.getJSON(url, {})   
    .done (function(data) { 
      var features = (new ol.format.GeoJSON()).readFeatures(data);
      vectorLayerSource.addFeatures(features);
    })  
    .fail(function(data) {    
      console.log("geojson error in "+url);  
    })
  ).then(function() { 
      console.log("geojson file "+url+" loaded");
  });
}
```